# HandlebarsJS break loop

Tags: javascript, xml, handlebars.js

I'm using handelBarsJS to convert JSON to XML  .

I have this example i'm working on : I have a list "Output" :

```
"output":[
    {
        "name":"Name1",
        "URI":"Link1",
        "Ref":"ref1"
    }, {
        "name":"Name2",
        "URI":"Link2",
        "Ref":"ref2"
    }, {  
        "name":"Name3",
        "URI":"Link3"
    }, {  
        "name":"Name4",
        "URI":"Link4"
    }
],
```

and I have this XML template

```
<!-- output -->
{{#output}} {{^Ref}}
<outputs>
    <OutputList>
{{/Ref}} {{/output}}  
       {{#output}}{{^Ref}} 
        <output name="{{name}}" xlink:href="{{URI}}" />
        {{/Ref}} {{/output}} 
{{#output}} {{^Ref}}
    </OutputList>
</outputs>
{{{/Ref}} {{/output}}
```

What i want to do is to retreive only Output's elements that dosent have the attribute "Ref", example of the output XML format i want :

```
<!-- output -->
<outputs>
    <OutputList>
        <output name="Name3" xlink:href="Link3" />
        <output name="Name4" xlink:href="Link4" />
      </OutputList>
</outputs>
```

And in case there's only Output elements with attribute Ref, i need to show nothing in the XML File, because i need to validate it against an XSD schema .

I need to when Handelbars itterate on each output element and find that there's an output element with ref attribute it adds this Only Once like breaking/exiting the loop after  :

```
<outputs><OutputList> 
</OutputList> </outputs>
```

Comment: If you provide JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) with the same sample code working and current output vs expected output, you are more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by simply deleting Outputs elements with ref attribute before applying my XML template to my JSON Object.

This is what my working XML template looks like :

```
  <!-- output -->
{{#if output}} 
<outputs>
    <OutputList>
 {{/if}}   
        {{#output}}
        <output name="{{name}}" xlink:href="{{URI}}" />
         {{/output}} 
{{#if output}} 
    </OutputList>
</outputs>
{{/if}}
```

Hope this helps some newbies like myself .

Answer (score 2):

Your template seems quite complex, you'll only need a `each` loop and `unless` helper.

Template:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <outputs>
       <OutputList>
            {{#each output}}
                {{#unless Ref}}
                <output name="{{name}}" xlink:href="{{URI}}" />
                {{/unless}}
            {{/each}}
        </OutputList>
    </outputs>
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
var json = {
    "output":[
        {
            "name":"Name1",
            "URI":"Link1",
            "Ref":"ref1"
        }, {
            "name":"Name2",
            "URI":"Link2",
            "Ref":"ref2"
        }, {  
            "name":"Name3",
            "URI":"Link3"
        }, {  
            "name":"Name4",
            "URI":"Link4"
        }
    ]
};

var source   = $("#template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var xml = template(json);
```

Output (`var xml`):

```
<outputs>
   <OutputList>
            <output name="Name3" xlink:href="Link3" />
            <output name="Name4" xlink:href="Link4" />
    </OutputList>
</outputs>
```

Fiddle (see console): http://jsfiddle.net/zba1g0dv/5/

Comment: I have managed to do the same but the problem with this template is that when there's no outputs elements with attribute Ref there will be something like this as an XML output :
    <outputs><OutputList> 
    </OutputList> </outputs>

which i won't be able to validate against my xsd schema.

Comment: Could you post an example XML for the situation when theres no elements with the ref key that you could validate

Comment: Like i posted below, i delete elements with ref keys before applying my xml template, and in my XML template i test if the output list is not empty, if theres elements in the output list i add those tags :
    <outputs><OutputList> </OutputList> </outputs>

else, there will be nothing in my xml which ill be able to validate in this case